# LiveView throws no component for CID error in console

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I have a liveview called `Menu` with 3 Live Component `Categories`, `Products`, and `Variants`

`phx-click` set up on each category, product, so when click on category, handle_event will 
return assign(socket, :products, products) `ProductsComponent` will products for the clicked category, and click on product, Variants will show.

And the handle_events are inside the Menu View

```
defmodule MyAppWeb.Admin.LocationLive.Menu do
  use MyAppWeb, :live_view

  import MyAppWeb.Admin.LocationLive.Helpers,
    only: [
      get_categories: 1,
      get_products: 2,
      get_variants: 2
    ]

  alias MyApp.Manager.Base

  @impl true
  def mount(%{"id" => location_id}, _session, socket) do
    case Base.get_location(location_id) do
      nil ->
        {:noreply, redirect(socket, Routes.admin_business_path(MyAppWeb.Endpoint, :index))}

      location ->
        {:ok,
         socket
         |> assign(:page_title, "Menu")
         |> assign(:location, location)
         |> assign(:products, [])
         |> assign(:variants, [])
         |> assign(:selected_category_id, nil)
         |> assign(:selected_product_id, nil)
         |> assign(:categories, get_categories(location)), temporary_assigns: [categories: []]}
    end
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_event(
        "show-products",
        %{"category" => category_id},
        socket
      ) do
    location = get_location(socket)

    {:noreply,
     socket
     |> assign(:products, get_products(location, category_id))
     |> assign(:variants, [])
     |> assign(:selected_category_id, category_id)}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_event(
        "show-variants",
        %{"product" => product_id},
        socket
      ) do
    location = get_location(socket)

    {:noreply,
     socket
     |> assign(:variants, get_variants(location, product_id))
     |> assign(:selected_product_id, product_id)}
  end

  defp get_location(socket) do
    socket.assigns.location
  end
end
```

`menu.html.leex`

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="<%= row_parts_class(4) %>">
    <div class="align-items-center <%= row_parts_class(12) %>">
      <h5 class="h5 font-weight-bold text-default">Categories</h5>
    </div>
    <%= live_component @socket, MyAppWeb.Admin.LocationLive.CategoriesComponent,
      categories: @categories,
      location: @location,
      id: "categories-component"
    %>
  </div>
  <div class="<%= row_parts_class(4) %>">
    <div class="align-items-center <%= row_parts_class(12) %>">
      <h5 class="h5 font-weight-bold text-default">Products</h5>
    </div>
    <%= live_component @socket, MyAppWeb.Admin.LocationLive.ProductsComponent,
      products: @products,
      location: @location,
      category_id: @selected_category_id,
      id: "products-component"
    %>
  </div>
  <div class="<%= row_parts_class(4) %>">
    <div class="align-items-center <%= row_parts_class(12) %>">
      <h5 class="h5 font-weight-bold text-default">Variants</h5>
    </div>
    <%= live_component @socket, MyAppWeb.Admin.LocationLive.VariantsComponent,
      variants: @variants,
      location: @location,
      product_id: @selected_product_id,
      id: "variants-component"
    %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that after clicking on product, and variants are shown, then I go back to click on another category, it will show new products, but the old variants are still there. So I tried to `assign(socket, :variants, [])` in category handle_event, but it throws an error in console `no component for CID 2`, and the old Products and Variants components remain unchanged.

[image]

Anyone has any idea how to fix this or maybe a workaround to clear out the VariantsComponent everytime a category is clicked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it, I got the variants to hide by setting `selected_product_id` to nil and put an `if` statement around the Variants live component

```
<%= if @selected_product_id do %>
  <%= live_component @socket, MyAppWeb.Admin.LocationLive.VariantsComponent,
    variants: @variants,
    location: @location,
    product_id: @selected_product_id,
    id: "variants-component"
  %>
<% end %>
```

and inside of menu

```
{:noreply,
 socket
 |> assign(:products, get_products(location, category_id))
 |> assign(:selected_product_id, nil)
 |> assign(:selected_category_id, category_id)}
```

I guess this way, when live view pushes change to the view, it will check the if it should render the live component, which ends up hiding the variants component when `selected_product_id` is nil